# Error: exec is not supported when executing Mongo Db Realm function

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, realm

This is the code of my realm function:

```
    exports = function(changeEvent) {
  
    
    const topicName = 'topicname';
    const data = JSON.stringify({foo: 'bar'});
    
    //const {PubSub} = require('pubsub');
    const {PubSub} = require('@google-cloud/pubsub')
    
    // Creates a client; cache this for further use
   const pubSubClient = new PubSub();
    
   async function publishMessageWithCustomAttributes() {
  // Publishes the message as a string, e.g. "Hello, world!" or JSON.stringify(someObject)
  const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(data);
  console.log(data);

  // Add two custom attributes, origin and username, to the message
  const customAttributes = {
    origin: 'nodejs-sample',
    username: 'gcp',
  };

  const messageId = await pubSubClient
    .topic(topicName)
    .publish(dataBuffer, customAttributes);
  console.log(`Message ${messageId} published.`);
}

publishMessageWithCustomAttributes().catch(console.error);

};
```

When I execute it from the mongo Db Atlas Realm function I get: Error: exec is not supported.
Any hint on how to solve this issue or how to debug the Realm function?

Comment: Sure. Some basic troubleshooting will get you going. Comment out all the lines and then uncomment them one at a time, running the code between each until it errors. Then you'll know the section of code causing the problem.

Comment: I found out that this is the instruction that causes the error: const messageId = await pubSubClient.topic(topicName).publish(dataBuffer); But I cannot understand what the error means.

Comment: Well, that line of code doesn't exit, as in, in the question. Your code has a `customAttributes` parameter being passed.

Comment: Yes. I saw that there is no line of code with exec. I wrote to Mongo support and they told me that exec is not supported. I don't understand what does it mean.